# Que signifie "croulure" ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Bonjour,

Savez-vous, s'il vous plaît, ce que signifie le mot ***croulure*** ? Je ne l'ai pas trouvé dans les dictionnaires... s'agit-il d'un néologisme ?

Le mot apparaît dans la description d'une scène à l'hôpital : "Il y en avait des drôles de bouilles, des difficiles d'imaginer comme **croulures** finies, qui duraient pourtant emmerdeurs des mois et des mois..." (CÉLINE, 2015, p. 159).

Merci d'avance !

Comment: On le trouve dans Google Translate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Croulure* est à rapprocher de *[croulant](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/croulant)*, plus courant. Quelqu'un de *croulant* est quelqu'un de vieux et en mauvaise santé, du verbe *crouler* qui signifie tomber en ruines. *Croulure* est plus fort, plus insultant, et insiste plus sur le mauvais état que sur l'âge (quelqu'un qui est usé par la maladie, le travail ou par la drogue, par exemple, peut être une croulure avant d'être croulant). Le [*Petit traité de l'injure* de Pierre Merle](https://www.librairie-gallimard.com/livre/9782757827116-petit-traite-de-l-injure-dictionnaire-humoristique-pierre-merle/) a une entrée pour [croulure](https://books.google.fr/books?id=E6LLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT126&lpg=PT126&dq=%22croulure%22&source=bl&ots=CbQYmi5Kca&sig=ACfU3U0jMYatu02iOg30Kkh4ADS8h3kMEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjqbGv_aHyAhVDzIUKHbMhAJUQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=%22croulure%22&f=false) :

> CROULURE Ne pas confondre avec croulant (vieillard), puisqu'il n'est pas forcément ici question d'âge, mais de délabrement.

*Croulure* est effectivement rare et je ne le trouve pas dans des dictionnaires généralistes, mais ce n'est pas une invention de Céline. Le [*Verbiaire* de Chaunes et Sylvoisal](http://salon-litteraire.linternaute.com/fr/chaunes/review/1936634-le-verbiaire-de-chaunes-et-sylvoisal-le-baroque-dans-l-ordre-alphabetique) a une entrée pour [croulure](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eBVjdwy39ZsC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22croulure%22&source=bl&ots=cY0xz1kSVx&sig=ACfU3U0YPjvwUv6DLxN2XVHQNF_pEiDXYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjqbGv_aHyAhVDzIUKHbMhAJUQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22croulure%22&f=false):

> À la fois plus fort et plus usé que roulure. « Les filles des plus grandes maisons font les plus belles croulures. » (Sade) « Le Bien-Aimé ne parut souvent qu'une croulure aux yeux de ses maîtresses. » (Mme de Créqui — Mémoires)

Une *[roulure](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/roulure)*, dans ce sens, est quelqu'un de vieux ; le terme n'est pas forcément péjoratif, alors que *croulure* est une insulte. (*Roulure* peut aussi désigner une prostituée âgée ou usée et qui n'est plus attrayante ; dans ce sens, c'est très péjoratif.)

Answer (score 0):

C'est un mot à rapprocher du mot « croulant » ;  encore une fois, la déformation est probablement due à Céline.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/croulant)) III.− Subst., fam., gén. au masc. plur. Personne âgée (supra).
> ♦ Ces barbons, tout de même, ces décatis, ces croulants, quelles bizarres confitures! (Arnoux, Solde,1958, p. 118).
> − Spéc. (dans le lang. des adolescents). Les parents. Synon. les vieux :
> 3. ...s'il n'y avait pas eu la corvée de ballade avec tes parents j'y serais allé aujourd'hui aussi. − Tu n'es pas gentil pour moi en disant ça. − Avoue que ce n'est pas rigolo de se promener avec les croulants. Queneau, Loin de Rueil,1944, p. 50.

Le fait que l'on trouve directement après ce mot la remarque « qui duraient pourtant emmerdeurs des mois et des mois », laquelle est un commentaire sur la longévité surprenante de ces personnes appelées « croulures », est une indication que ce mot ne signifie en termes « neutres » rien d'autre que « personnes agées ».